# Sending params in pop/dismiss

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got 3 routes. When I move from 1st to 2nd I need to pass a parameter:
`this.navCtrl.push(ReadyPage, { newGame: true });`

But I also need to pass sometimes this parameter as well when I moving from 3rd to 2nd.

I'm trying with this but doesn't work:
`this.viewCtrl.dismiss({ newGame: true });`

Comparing both methods `dismiss` doesn't seem to have that option (unless it's called `data` instead `params`):
`abstract push(page: Page | string, params?: any, opts?: NavOptions, done?: TransitionDoneFn): Promise<any>;`
`dismiss(data?: any, role?: string, navOptions?: NavOptions): Promise<any>;`

Comment: Can you explain your problem with more details, please? What type of page you have there? In which case you want to pass what params?

Comment: No extra explanation is required apart from that I have 3 pages and I want to send a parameter (no matters what and when) backwards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Last page:

```
 this.navCtrl.getPrevious().data.newGame = true;
 this.navCtrl.pop();
```

2nd page:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
     this.newGame = this.navParams.get('newGame')|| null;
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew that you can do this, but it makes sense when you think about it. Why use events or callbacks if you can just grab and update whats inside the navStack directly

Comment: Excellent, best way, avoiding call back hell

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dani! I wanted to use the default back arrow from Ionic navigation but passing data to the previous page on stack. What worked for me was using ionViewWillLeave() on the last page but without using pop() as it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

visit [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-navcontroller-pop-with-params/58104) if you can solve your problem this way, it suggests using `pop()` with params when going back from page 3 to page 2

pass in a callback when transitioning

```
// callback...
 myCallbackFunction = function(_params) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             resolve();
         });
 }

 // push page...
 this.navController.push(OtherPageComponent, {
    callback: myCallbackFunction
});
```

in the OtherPageComponent

```
 this.callback = this.navParams.get("callback")

 this.callback(param).then(()=>{
    this.navController.pop();
 });
```

Comment: between this option and the one using events which one would your say is the best one?

Comment: I tried this way but didn't work. I'm pretty sure is my fault but it may also be the version of Ionic. In other hand, the events work, but it seems that it needs more time to take the value from the event

Comment: And also why is this callback on previous page push(). Shouldn't it be inside ionViewDidEnter() for example?

Comment: Found a quicker way. I posted it. Might be a new way

Comment: I get error, Callback is not a function on ionic 4,
"ERROR TypeError: this.callback is not a function"